# Get Quote from Order Success Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, quote

I tried to get quote from success order observer like this:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer instance="Vendor\Salesman\Observer\Customer\OrderSuccess" name="lime_salesman_observer_onepage_success_action" />
    </event>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Customer/OrderSuccess.php

```
public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
}
```

but i got an error like this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   getQuoteId() on null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By using this observer you can get only order_ids
> if you want to get quote_id you need to load order object.
>
> load order using order id after then you can get quote_id by using ***$order->getQuoteId();***

1.etc/event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
            <observer name="namespace_modulename_observer_getquote" instance="Namespace\ModuleName\Observer\Getquote" />
      </event>
</config>
```

2.Observer\Getquote.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Observer;

class Getquote implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId[0]);
        echo $order->getQuoteId(); exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266549/how-to-create-duplicate-new-quote-from-old-order-quote-magento-1-7

Answer (score 2):

In this observer you have `order_ids` not order object:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Observer;

use \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;

class Quote implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{  
    /**
     * @param OrderFactory $orderFactory
     * @param QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    */
    public function __construct(
        OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     ) {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
       $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrdeIds();
       $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderIds[0]);
       $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
       return $quote;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event is dispatched with the below code:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
    ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
);
```

So it does not contain the order object, but it does contain the orderIds.

Comment: so how can i get the order id?

Comment: $array = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();